# Javascript revert part of string not working?

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

Working on this [reverse words in string](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string)

I tried to revert part of the string, given the input string, start_index, end_index, but it seems no effect.

```
var myrev = function(str, s, e) {
    let tmp;
    while(s<e) {
        tmp = str[s];        
        str[s] = str[e];        
        str[e] = tmp;

        s++;
        e--;
    }

    return str;
}
```

full code

```
// revert the words in this string: " the  sky is   blue "
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    let a = s.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    a = a.split('');

    // s === "eulb si yks eht"
    s = a.reverse().join('');

    let i, j, ind;
    ind = s.indexOf(' ', 0);
    i=0;
    j=ind-1;

    // expect s === "blue si yks eht", but still "eulb si yks eht", why???????
    s = myrev(s, i, j);

    console.log(s)
};


var myrev = function(str, s, e) {
    let tmp;
    while(s<e) {
        tmp = str[s];        
        str[s] = str[e];        
        str[e] = tmp;

        s++;
        e--;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Does it seem I need to pass a string as a reference?

Comment: Strings are immutable.Strings are copied by value not reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `split()` by a `\s+`(one or more space). And `join()` by a `' '`(whitespace) not empty string `''`. There is no need of `myrev` for leetcode problem. The below code is passing all tests for leetcode.

```
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    return s.trim().split(/\s+/).reverse().join(' ')
};
```

The notation `str[index]` in only to access the letter of string at that index. Changing it will not change the string. You can first convert string to array of letters and then use `join()` at end.

```js
var myrev = function(str, s, e) {
    str = [...str]
    let tmp;
    while(s<e) {
        tmp = str[s];        
        str[s] = str[e];        
        str[e] = tmp;
        s++;
        e--;
    }
    return str.join('');
}

console.log(myrev("eulb si yks eht",0,3))
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, but is it a way to modify the string in place?

Comment: @kenpeter, did you read the first comment under your question? ... "immutable"...

Comment: @kenpeter I couldnot understand what you mean. If `str = 'abc'`. `str[1] = str[2]` will not change the real string. You can use `slice()` for that.

Comment: @kenpeter here u can find a good explanation of the differences https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: @MaheerAli, myrev(str, s, e), str: input string, s: start_index, e: end_index. e.g. "eulb si yks eht" ==> "blue si yks eht", if start_index = 0, end_index = 3

Answer (score 0):

string can’t be modified

```
var myrev = function(str, s, e) {
let tmpArr = str.split("")
while(s<e) {
    tmp = tmpArr[s];        
    tmpArr[s] = tmpArr[e];        
    tmpArr[e] = tmp;
    s++;
    e--;
}
return tmpArr.join("");
```

}